# racket: get package checksum

Tags: package, version, racket

I'd like to get the checksum for an installed package without using `raco pkg show -l <PKG-NAME>`. Something like:

```
(define scribble-checksum (get-checksum "scribble"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [pkg/lib](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/lib.html) API:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/format pkg/lib)

(define (get-checksum str)
  (define tbl (installed-pkg-table #:scope 'installation))
  (define info (hash-ref tbl str))
  (define chk (pkg-info-checksum info))
  (~a chk #:max-width 8))
```

Then you can do things like:

```
(get-checksum "typed-racket")
;; Returns: "f53314a2" for me, today
```